# Valid Reasons to Break up with a Chavrusa?

Tags: torah-study, chavrusa

What are valid reasons to break up with a teacher or a chavrusa?

What causes issues in a chavrusa relationship/a teacher-student relationship? Are all these issues reasons to stop learning with someone? If you have solutions to the problems please explain them.

Comment: Welcom to Mi Yodyea, bewarethecleats! I'm sorry to hear about the issues you're experiencing. From the background story you provide, it sounds like what you're dealing with is more about friendships in general than chavrusa relationships in particular. Could you possibly [edit] your second paragraph, with the actual question in it, to make it sharper and more answerable? What makes you think that there's a finite corpus of valid "break up" reasons? I'd recommend taking out the even more general "what causes issues" and possibly making that a separate post, asking for issues to look out for.